# Changing Theme in Android Manifest Crashes App

Tags: android, eclipse

Basically I tried changing the theme in my Android Manifest from.. android:theme="@style/AppTheme" to.. "@android:style/Theme.Dialog". I followed the developer android "styles and Themes" page. When I plug in my galaxy S3 the app compiles with no errors. But on my phone it says "Unfortunately, (app) has stopped".

The Logcat says  "You need to use Theme.AppCompat theme or descendant with this activity " .

I do not understand why, I followed a simple change of theme from the android developer website http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html.

Any help will be greatly appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Can you include your code in a readable formatted way? Thanks

Comment: literally standard code when you create new android application on eclipse. I changed NOTHING, apart from the theme as stated above..? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

same problem here, i have tried eclipse and android studio, but the problem still coming. The debug said, only descendent of Theme.AppCompat is able to use. When I change to @android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar error will show up and the app crash.

I have found the solution, you just have to coenter image description herepy true from themse.xml to styles.xml.

Comment: After days of looking around, I believe that when you extend ActionBarActivity it indicates your using AppCombat. This means you will need to extend theme from Theme.AppCombat.